# WebView "failed to load resouce" when Chrome loads same URL fine

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

Suddenly my Android WebView app stopped working.  When I use Chrome Inspect to remotely debug, all I see is "Failed to load resource" in the console.   When I inspect the network request, only request headers and form data is shown, there is no response.  Under the "response" tab it says "Failed to load response data".  Under "Timing" it says "Connection Start" and under that it says "Stalled"  with a time of 13.85ms.

If I insert debugging breakpoints in my XMLHttpRequest, I see one callback with this.readyState == 1, and a second with this.readyState == 4, this.response == this.responseText == this.responseType == this.responseURL == statusText == "", status == 0, that is, everything completely empty with no error code.

On the server (running Apache2) there is nothing whatsoever in access_log or error_log, suggesting the server isn't even hearing any kind of request.

Yet if I load the exact same URL from Chrome instead of in a WebView everything loads fine.

How can I troubleshoot this problem further?

Update: Backing out of the WebView in my app and then re-opening it seems to have fixed the problem, but I would still like to understand what happened.

Comment: please show your code..easier for us to find the problem..

Comment: @ZeroOne Just a standard XMLHttpRequest that has worked a million times before and started working again after restarting the WebView.  My interest is in the lack of usable information in the developer tools (no errors shown other than the one i listed) and how I can troubleshoot in this situation.